# Yii2 Infinite scroll: Getting elem.offset(...) is undefined error on ajax load

Tags: php, jquery, infinite-scroll, yii2-basic-app

I am using [Infinite scroll](https://github.com/DarkCs/yii2-infinite-scroll). I am using it in following manner in index.php

```
echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'options' => [
        'class' => '.list-view',
    ],
    'itemView' => '_view',
    'summary' => false,
    'layout' => '{items}<div class="pagination-wrap">{pager}</div>',
    'pager' => [
        'class' => \darkcs\infinitescroll\InfiniteScrollPager::className(),
        'paginationSelector' => '.pagination-wrap',
        'pjaxContainer' => $pjax->id,
    ],
]);
```

My _view.php page

```
<div class="view media col-sm-6 col-lg-4 job_container">
    <div class="widget display-table shadow-z-1 text-center">

        <div class="view-info text-left">

            <b>Address : </b><?Php echo $locationArray['fullAddress']; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <b>Owner : </b><?Php echo $ownerName; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <b>Tenant : </b><?Php echo $tenantName; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now when i scroll down page i get following js error

> TypeError: elem.offset(...) is undefined  var elemTop =
>   elem.offset().top;

In my infinitescroll.js

```
 function isScrolledToBottom(elem, container) {
        var containerViewTop = container.scrollTop();
        var containerViewBottom = containerViewTop + container.height();

        var elemTop = elem.offset().top; // Here i am getting error
        var elemBottom = elemTop + elem.height();

        return (elemBottom - options.bufferPx <= containerViewBottom);
    }
```

I have tried many time. but i can't get success. Any help Please.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dot in the class name

```
'options' => [
    'class' => 'list-view',
],
```

Comment: i removed it. error not coming. but on scrolling data is not coming

Comment: Hey. I can get next page record on console. but that are not appending to my listview. What is wrong?